# ServiceNow Performance analytics - calculate average response time

Tags: performance, analytics, servicenow, sn

I have to create performance analytics widget for response time (response_*time) on table Client transactions (syslog*_transactions), but in analytics hub I do not see correct data.

I tried to create Indicator source with a set of conditions and also Indicator, which is set to average response_time field. You can the report I am currently seeing, but I want to make average of every day, which makes this report not correct because some days I have response time over 20.000ms. Don't know where might be the problem if it is in data collector, or indicator itself. Thanks for any advice.[image][image][image]

Comment: Are you sure that the average is wrong? It could be that one outlier is skewing the whole result. You may want to target the client transaction table instead, and filter the crazy outliers (you know.. the users that pull 500.000 records at a time)